# Using Gems with Ruby On Rails: Undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, captcha

There's this snazzy captcha that asks questions rather than displaying pictures. You can read about it at [textcaptcha.com](http://textcaptcha.com). Anyway. I want to use that with Ruby on Rails. A developer by the name of Matt Hutchinson wrote a Gem for easily connecting to the API. He has a [set of instructions next to his source files on github](https://github.com/matthutchinson/acts_as_textcaptcha). Anyway, It looks pretty simple but in trying to implement it I get this error every time:

```
undefined method `acts_as_textcaptcha' for #<Class:0x104098508>
Rails.root: /Users/cory/Documents/Learning/RoR/dpt

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/citation.rb:20
app/controllers/citations_controller.rb:29:in `new'
```

The root of my question has a bit less to do with this specific gem, and a little more with how gems work. I've installed the gem, and then bundled it inside of my rails app, it should be accessible (as I understand it). I see references to the gem in the `gemfile.rb` and the `gemfile.lock`, but again and again it tells me I'm using and undefined method.

The gem should be defining the method for me, should it not? Or is there something that I manually have to do?

Just let me know if there is any other info that would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: There are some changes that aren't noticed automatically, even in the `development` environment; for those changes, you need to restart the server. This might be one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, jeez. It's working now. It could be that I restarted the server, but I'm not positive. What I did was installed RubyMine to see if I could use it's debugger, in doing so it required that I run the bundle install (it chose some different versions of some dependancies) through there, and also stop my other webrick server, to run the one through the RubyMine console. I did so, it gave me errors, when when I went back to my other installer it worked!? 
Anyway, I've got my question resolved, but in the event that anyone looks this up, these are my current gems:

```
$ bundle install
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.0) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.4.2) 
Using activemodel (3.0.0) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.0) 
Using arel (1.0.1) 
Using activerecord (3.0.0) 
Using activeresource (3.0.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) 
Using acts_as_textcaptcha (2.2.0) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.0) 
Using rails (3.0.0) 
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Thanks all! 
But if you are trying this, do try restarting the server first as suggested, I wish I knew if that would have worked :D

Comment: I really think that just restarting my local server was all that I had to do. I'm not very familiar with installing gems. Well, hopefully this is a good reminder to someone else that forgets. :)